Lilypond - Combining expressions without duplicated noteheads
I'm setting a piece and want to have the parts all printed out separately but also a main score with all the parts for the conductor.
Here is my try for the combined score:
\version "2.24.3"

parta = { c'4 d' e' }
partb = { c'4 f'  b' }
partc = { g'4 a' b' }

\new Staff
{
    \new Voice {
        <<
            \partc
            \parta
            \partb
        >>
    }
}


My problem is that I have some voices playing the same note, but I don't want these notes to be printed multiple times, the notes should just be combined to show the chord that is played in total.

Well, one way you can do this is force all the voices to \voiceOne like this:
\new Staff
{
    << 
       \new Voice { \voiceOne \partc } 
       \new Voice { \voiceOne \parta } 
       \new Voice { \voiceOne \partb } 
    >>
}

But you might want to take a look at \partCombine as another way to combine parts for a conductor.

A problem with using \voiceOne is that it forces all stems up.  You could fix this with \stemNeutral, but there are other things that \voiceOne does (such as changing the rest position) that you’d also need to revert.

Unfortunately, \partCombine only works with two parts.

Yes, \partCombine is great for two expressions. Do you know how hard it would be to expand it for more than two parts?

This is the closest thing I could find: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/snippets/simultaneous-notes_003a-two-_005cpartcombine-pairs-on-one-staff

You could give each voice it's own staff or at least split some of them appart:
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/grouping-staves
Or as the other answer has mentioned you could use different voices:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices
Though you might also use the other voices such as \voiceTwo, \voiceThree where the odd ones are higher on the staff with stems upwards and the even ones with their stem downwards so even if they happen to hit the same note you should see that by the direction of the stems.
